# Extract all rows from excel data set when multiple cells contains certain text

Tags: excel-formula

**This question was asked and the answer *ALMOST* works for me.**

THE PROBLEM

[image: IMAGE OF EXCEL DATA SET]

Very simply from the above dataset I wish to recreate this range but filter for only select BLOOD TYPE O.

The answer given is:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("O",INDIRECT("$A2:$A"&COUNTA(A:A)))),ROW(INDIRECT("$A2:$A"&COUNTA(A:A))),""),ROW()-1)),"")
```

This works **only in ROW 2.** I have tried everything to get this to begin in a new row and column (I also want the data to be in a different row and column) but whenever i update the formula, nothing is returned.

[image: My Own Attempt at Moving the Data Set and Updating the Formula Which FAILED]

ED please see this new picture:
[image: New Picture with Your Formula Attempt]

Comment: When you say this range, what do you mean?  Are you just trying to generate a list of of people that match the blood type?

Comment: @ForwardEd Thank you for your answer! However, this is not working for me. I want to pull all the rows with Adam Graves for example, but i also want to be able to change the name for which i pull the data. Please see new picture above. Nothing is coming back when i enter the formula.

Comment: I got confused with your question.  the first part about the blood type was not relating to image two and 3.  I think I understand now though

Comment: For starters, change the `#REF` in your formula to `$K$2` and change the `C4` references to `A1`

Comment: @ForwardEd Thank you so so much!!!!!!!!!!!!! It worked perfectly.

Comment: If you believe its the best answer, please mark it accepted.

Answer (score 0):

[image: POC]

In the image above, I place your example data set in the range C3:F13.  Based on your question it sounded like you were trying to filter your list based on blood type, but I was not sure if you just wanted names, or some other combination of columns.  This solution assumes you want all columns in the order they are presented.  I placed the following formula in I5:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($D$4:$F$13,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($C$4:$C$13)-3)/($C$4:$C$13=$I$2),ROW(A1)),COLUMN(A1)),"")
```

In I2 is the value of the blood type you are filtering your list for.

in the formula above, adjust the ranges to suit your data range locations.  The -3 in the formula is for the number of header rows before the data starts.  If you have headers or other space and your first piece of data was in row 15 then you would need to change -3 to -14.